# compare function value with a numerical value in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I want to use ifelse to return 0 if the function gives out a value 0, Otherwise gives out 1.
Code is as following:

```
ifelse((function() get_attribute(exp.sim, "Tx1.Event"))==0, 0, 1))
```

But I got this error message:
comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
Anyone knows how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try

```
ifelse((function() get_attribute(exp.sim, "Tx1.Event"))()==0, 0, 1))
```

where an extra `()` is added in front of `==`, which makes you run your lambda function.

Comment: Thank you and it works for me now. Could you explain further more? I'm so curious about the theory...

Comment: @kaiyuwei If you try `class(function() get_attribute(exp.sim, "Tx1.Event"))`, you will see it is a `function`, but it is anonymous since you didn't assign it to any object. Note that it is a function ONLY, which gives you returned values as long as you have input arguments. If you add `()`, that means we pass arguments to this function (although it is empty argument), then we will get a value returned from the function.